# Searching the right format for SOAP access

Tags: java, web-services, soap

in order to check validation of turkish personal identification numbers, the gouverment in turkey has this free service: https://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/Service/KPSPublic.asmx?op=TCKimlikNoDogrula

over SOAP you may check wether or not a ID-Number is valid.

but how ever i can not use this service with this code

```
package sevsoap;

import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class SevSOAP
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    try
    {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "https://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/Service/KPSPublic.asmx?op=TCKimlikNoDogrula";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        // Process the SOAP Response
        printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

        soapConnection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception
{
    SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");


    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("TCKimlikNoDogrula");

    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("TCKimlikNo");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("10000000146");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Ad");
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("Mustafa");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Soyad");
    soapBodyElem3.addTextNode("Atatürk");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem4 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("DogumYili");
    soapBodyElem4.addTextNode("1881");

    MimeHeaders headers = message.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS/TCKimlikNoDogrula");

    message.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
    message.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();

    return message;
}

/**
 * Method used to print the SOAP Response
 */
private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
}
}
```

The message is sent in the following format:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<TCKimlikNoDogrula>
<TCKimlikNo>10000000146</TCKimlikNo>
<Ad>Mustafa</Ad>
<Soyad>Atatürk</Soyad>
<DogumYili>1881</DogumYili>
</TCKimlikNoDogrula>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but it seems like the server requires me to send my query only in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<TCKimlikNoDogrula xmlns="http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS">
  <TCKimlikNo>10000000146</TCKimlikNo>
  <Ad>Mustafa</Ad>
  <Soyad>Atatürk</Soyad>
  <DogumYili>1881</DogumYili>
</TCKimlikNoDogrula>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It doesn't matter to what i am changing the Namespace, it still puts out this error from the server:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; T.C. Kimlik No değeri 10000000000 değerinden büyük veya eşit ve 89999999999 değerinden küçük veya eşit olmalıdır.
    T.C. Kimlik No alanına girdiğiniz değer geçerli bir T.C. Kimlik Numarası değildir.
    Ad alanını boş geçemezsiniz.
    Soyad alanını boş geçemezsiniz.
    Doğum Yıl değeri 1000 değerinden büyük veya eşit ve 9999 değerinden küçük veya eşit olmalıdır.
    </faultstring>
<detail/>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It says that i can't submit these variables empty, they must contain data in order to process my query.

So, what could i do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing one default namespace in your code. Please try it!

```
 // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("TCKimlikNoDogrula", "", "http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS");

    (...)
```

I use empty string for default namespace. I tried your code with this modification and I get this response:

```
Response SOAP Message = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><TCKimlikNoDogrulaResponse xmlns="http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS"><TCKimlikNoDogrulaResult>false</TCKimlikNoDogrulaResult></TCKimlikNoDogrulaResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked for me!! NOTE: In order to receive true Messages, Firstname and Lastname must be written all UPPERCASE and turkish letters have to be used!!!

Answer (score 2):

I am in a habit of generating WS clients through eclipse, it did all the hard work for me here as well. Below are the step by step instructions how you create them:

[image: Select File menu, pick New and then Other]
[image: Pick Web Service Client wizard]
[image: Enter the wsdl url]

Please note the changed url for direct wsdl I have used here: https://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/Service/KPSPublic.asmx?wsdl

Then I write your caller, below is the entire code:

```
package tr.gov.nvi.tckimlik.WS;

    public class TurkishWS {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
                KPSPublicLocator loc = new KPSPublicLocator();
                KPSPublicSoap soap = loc.getKPSPublicSoap();

                boolean ret = soap.TCKimlikNoDogrula(new Long("10000000146"),
                        "Mustafa", "Atatürk", 1881);

                System.out.println("My return : " + ret);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err
                        .println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**The result:**

```
My return : false
```

I have also tried the direct request through soapUI, below are the request and response:

**soapUI Request**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ws:TCKimlikNoDogrula>
         <ws:TCKimlikNo>10000000146</ws:TCKimlikNo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ws:Ad>Mustafa</ws:Ad>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ws:Soyad>Atatürk</ws:Soyad>
         <ws:DogumYili>1881</ws:DogumYili>
      </ws:TCKimlikNoDogrula>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**soapUI Response**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <TCKimlikNoDogrulaResponse xmlns="http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS">
         <TCKimlikNoDogrulaResult>false</TCKimlikNoDogrulaResult>
      </TCKimlikNoDogrulaResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Hope it helps your cause, and good luck!